# Checking if RigidBody is grounded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have  a GameObject with a Rigidbody, Mesh Collider, Skinned Mesh Renderer, and the below script.

I'm trying to check if it is Grounded, but the Console continuously spits out "Not Grounded!" when it is, so obviously something is wrong here. Can anyone please help?

```
public class GroundCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Height;
    bool IsGrounded;
    Ray ray;
    MeshRenderer renda;

    private void Start()
    {
        Height = renda.bounds.size.y;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, Height))
        {
            IsGrounded = true;
            Debug.Log("Grounded");
        }
        else
        {
            IsGrounded = false;
            Debug.Log("Not Grounded!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option for checking if the rigidBody is grounded is using the [OnTriggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) function.

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.Transform.Tag == "Ground")
        {
            IsGrounded = true;
            Debug.Log("Grounded");
        }
        else
        {
            IsGrounded = false;
            Debug.Log("Not Grounded!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked. I'm still confused as to why I wasn't able to get the other way to work even with the LocalBounds technique, but as for now I'm just glad to have something that DOES work. . . !

Comment: Anyway this approach is better for detecting collisions and touches most of the time

Comment: Good catch! But I'm curious, why this will work with that trigger and no on update? It's cause the collider is "touching very fast" it's other collider?

Comment: The trigger checks if there is a touch and the raycast uses a different method, it's more complicated to use the raycast but if used correctly is should work in the Update function.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to check if your rigidbody is grounded than collision checking and rays. But first, why is collision checking not a good idea: If your level is a single model the walls will too be tagged with the "Ground" tag and hitting a wall will return true, which you don't want. Rays can be used, but that's too much math you don't need to waste time with.

Instead of using new objects and methods, just check if the position is changing:

```
private float lastYposition;
private bool grounded;

void Start() {
    lastYposition = transform.position.y;
}

void Update() {
    grounded = (lastYposition == transform.position.y); // Checks if Y has changed since last frame
    lastYposition = transform.position.y;
}
```

From here it's up to you what logic you are going to add.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your code with a simple scene with a plane and a cube, and it works.

It only spawns NotGrounded when it's clearly "floating" arround or the object has the half of it's body outside the plane.

Check those things [drawing](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawRay.html) the Ray, this should give your more information about what is going wrong with your mesh.

Also if the problem is how the game is perceiving the Height of your Skinned Mesh you can also use [SkinnedMeshRenderer.localBounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer-localBounds.html) who returns the AABB of the object.

Comment: That is good to know. I've noticed that when I hit play, the "Height" stays at 0, so even though my SkinnedMeshRenderer has a mesh, it for some reason is not grabbing the mesh height at all. Investigating...

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe the second link could help to test more approaches ^^

Answer (score 1):

Get the closest contact point to the bottom. Check if the contact normal is within range.

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    var bottom = renderer.bounds.center;
    bottom.y -= renderer.bounds.extents.y;
    float minDist = float.PositiveInfinity;
    float angle = 180f;
    // Find closest point to bottom.
    for (int i = 0; i < collision.contactCount; i++)
    {
        var contact = collision.GetContact(i);
        var tempDist = Vector3.Distance(contact.point, bottom);
        if(tempDist < minDist)
        {
            minDist = tempDist;
            // Check how close the contact normal is to our up vector.
            angle = Vector3.Angle(transform.up, contact.normal);
        }
    }
    // Check if the angle is too steep.
    if (angle <= 45f) IsGrounded = true;
    else IsGrounded = false;
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    IsGrounded = false;
}
```

I came up with this answer after reading [amitklein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8772299/amitklein)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (transform.position.y == 0f)
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this approach to jump using addrelativeforce of rigid body only when the position of y in 0.

Comment: This won't work on things like platforms or slopes.